# Properties of a cumulative distribution function and rescaling

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a cumulative distribution function $F$.

Take $a: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ and $b: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)$. Let $a_s\equiv a(s)$ and $b_s\equiv b(s)$ for all $s \in (0,\infty)$.

Assume
$$
[F(a_sx+b_s)]^s=F(x), \quad\forall s>0
$$
could you help me to understand how this implies that

1. $$ [F(a_{st}x+b_{st})]^s=F\left(\frac{a_{st}}{a_s}x+\frac{b_{st}-b_s}{a_s}\right), \quad \forall s,t>0 $$

   $$\left[F\left(\frac{a_{st}}{a_s}x+\frac{b_{st}-b_s}{a_s}\right)\right]^t=F\left(\frac{a_{st}}{a_ta_s}x+\frac{b_{st}-b_s-a_sb_t}{a_sa_t}\right). \quad\forall s,t>0 $$

I don't understand how things are rescaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$
(F(a_s x + b_s))^s = F(x), \quad \forall s > 0, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
then for any $u > 0$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, take $(s, x) = \left( u, \dfrac{y - b_u}{a_u}  \right)$ to get$$
(F(y))^u = F\left( \frac{y - b_u}{a_u} \right).
$$
Now, for any $s, t > 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, take $(u, y) = (s, a_{st} x + b_{st})$ to get$$
(F(a_{st} x + b_{st}))^s = F\left( \frac{a_{st} x + b_{st} - b_s}{a_s} \right) = F\left( \frac{a_{st}}{a_s} x + \frac{b_{st} - b_s}{a_s} \right),
$$
and take $(u, y) = \left( t, \dfrac{a_{st}}{a_s} x + \dfrac{b_{st} - b_s}{a_s} \right)$ to get\begin{align*}
\left( F\left( \frac{a_{st}}{a_s} x + \frac{b_{st} - b_s}{a_s} \right) \right)^t &= F\left( \frac{1}{a_t} \left( \left( \frac{a_{st}}{a_s} x + \frac{b_{st} - b_s}{a_s} \right) - b_t \right) \right)\\
&= F\left( \frac{a_{st}}{a_s a_t} x + \frac{b_{st} - b_s - a_s b_t}{a_s a_t} \right).
\end{align*}